# How to format string with floating point?

Tags: c#, .net

In database I have a PRICE field type of float with value 54342.76 and I want to display it on  gridview as 54,342.76. How can format this values?

Comment: Side note: "PRICE field type of float" is bad idea in general... Precision of float is not good for most money related computations - use `decimal` instead.

Comment: Prices should be stored in decimal.  You do not want to run into floating point errors when dealing with money.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
float f = 54342.76F;
string s = f.ToString("0,0.000", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

You could use `c` specifier instead, however it prints currency sign also.
Use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` as in some localizations `,` thousands separator may be missing.

Also read [Decimal.ToString Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzeeb5cd.aspx), [Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx), [Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

this is what I use:

```
x.ToString("c")
```

Comment: this will also add currency sign in front of value like $54,342.76

Comment: @ZdravkoDanev you're right, however it depends on what the OP wants to display.

Answer (score 1):

```
String.Format("{0:n}", 54342.76F)
```

The N method is a good solution since it should respect the user's locale while others like:

```
String.Format("{0:#,###,###.##}", 54342.76F)
```

Could bypass current culture in some situations. Use `{0:n0}` instead of `{0:n}` if you want to display the number without decimals.

Answer (score 0):

In the past I have used this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11531/Money-DataType

It formats money perfectly when used in a DataGridView column.